# "make keys secret" failing with error "make: *** No rule to make target `keys'. Stop."

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am following this documentation https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#securing-the-service and tried the following command:

```
make keys secret KEY=/tmp/nginx.key CERT=/tmp/nginx.crt SECRET=/tmp/secret.json
```

But it is failing with error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `keys'.  Stop.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from [Makefile](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/https-nginx/Makefile) described above in link. You need to pull repo, change directory and run action from makefile.

`keys` action is next one (according that makefile)

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout $(KEY) -out $(CERT) -subj "/CN=nginxsvc/O=nginxsvc"
```

`make` command just runs actions described in `Makefile` (which you need to pull locally )

Comment: You need more than just the Makefile. You also need the default.conf file from https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/https-nginx/